# Trying to get a better understanding of the definition of measurement

Tags: theory, metrics, measurement

The book Software Metrics A Rigorous and Practical Approach defines measurement as

> ...the process by which numbers or symbols are assigned to
>   attributes of entities in the real world in such a way so as to
>   describe them according to clearly defined rules.

but what does it mean by "clearly defined rules"? Does this mean rules for assignment and comparison?

So, is “blue” a *measure* of the color of the room? Would "Bill" be a *measure* of the name of somebody? If not, why?

---

It then goes on to talk about the representational theory of measurement, defining measurement as a mapping from a domain to a range (Is this related to the earlier definition?):

> ...the mapping from the empirical world to the formal,
>   relational world.

and that:

> We can use real numbers, integers, or even a set of non-numeric
>   symbols.

as the range. Note that it includes non-numeric symbols because then it says:

> The representation condition asserts that a measurement mapping M must
>   map entities into numbers...

Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: non-numeric symbols are used to represent ordinals, often expressed as adjectives. For instance, "very hard", "hard", "tough", "easy", "very easy", represents a range of hardness. Because they are ordinals, you can assign numbers to them in that order. You can work with those ordinals to calculate medians, averages, and even higher-order statistics. You may need to train your observers to agree on what the designations mean, but once they are trained, you have a repeatable set of observations that can be compared over time and over place. This is the essence of measurement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does it mean by "clearly defined rules"?

It means *rules that are clearly defined.*  For example, [Source Lines of Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) can be defined as physical lines of code (the number of lines separated by a carriage return), or the number of logical statements.  Your assessment of the size of a program would depend greatly on which definition you use.

> is “blue” a measure of the color of the room?

How many shades of blue do you know of?

> It then goes on to talk about...

The point is that, if you define a measurement against a particular domain, someone else ought to be able to take your definition and come up with substantially the same *objective* measurement result as you did, given the same thing being measured, using whatever symbols you've chosen to define to make the measurement.

I say "substantially" because every measurement is subject to some margin of error, which should be a part of the measurement definition (i.e. everyone knows how accurate their slide rule is).